# PhantomJS incredibly slow and node process has CPU at 100%

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm messing around with phantomJS just to see how it works and it seems it is SUPER slow and pins the CPU while running. I feel like I must be doing something wrong. I feel like my code shouldn't pin the CPU and should only take a couple of seconds to run but ends up taking over 20 seconds. My code and output are below.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

const startTime = new Date().getTime();
let page = null;

function gimmeTime() {
  return new Date().getTime();
}

phantom.create(['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--load-images=no'], {
  phantomPath: './node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/bin/phantomjs'
})
  .then(instance => {
    phInstance = instance;
    return instance.createPage();
  })
  .then(p => {
    console.log(gimmeTime() - startTime);
    page = p;

    return page.open("http://www.slickdeals.com/");
  })
  .then(status => {
    console.log(gimmeTime() - startTime);
    return page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js');
  })
  .then(status => {
    console.log(gimmeTime() - startTime);
    return page.evaluate(function() {
      return href = 'http://slickdeals.com' + $('.fpGridBox:first .itemImageLink').attr('href');
    });
  })
  .then(href => {
    console.log(gimmeTime() - startTime);
    console.log('href is', href);
    return page.open(href);
  })
  .then(status => {
    console.log(gimmeTime() - startTime);
    return page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js');
  })
  .then(status => {
    console.log(gimmeTime() - startTime);
    return page.evaluate(function() {
      return $('title').text();
    });
  })
  .then(author => {
    console.log(author);
    console.log(gimmeTime() - startTime);
    phInstance.exit();
    return false;
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      phInstance.exit();
  });
```

Output:

```
436
6617
15921
15955
href is http://slickdeals.com/f/9159375-10-lb-musclepharm-combat-protein-powder-cookies-n-cream-60?src=featured-12075
15965
22150
Slickdeals: The Best Deals, Coupons, Promo Codes & Discounts
22163
```

Running:
Mac OS
Node: 7.2
Phantomjs: 2.1.1
Phantom: 3.1